# Parse elements with same names but with different attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am new to iPhone development and this question may be simple, but I don't know answer on it.

**Problem:** I have this XML code:

```
<im:image height="53">
     picture52x52.jpg
</im:image>

<im:image height="75">
     picture75x75.jpg
</im:image>

<im:image height="100">
     picture100x100.jpg
</im:image>
```

I need to parse only the second element (second element, second picture), but I don't know how. I parse always three elements but I need only one.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict  
{ 
        NSString *imageSize = [NSString stringWithString:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"]];
        if([imageSize isEqualToString:@"75"])
         { 
            // parse something like this
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these two methods intelligently :

```
parser:foundCharacters:
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```

Please refer this link - [Handling XML Elements and Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI)

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you one more solution, you can enclose picture name within CDATA, ie. generating xml like this -

```
<im:image height="53">
    <![CDATA[picture52x52.jpg]]>
</im:image>

<im:image height="75">
     <![CDATA[picture75x75.jpg]]>
</im:image>

<im:image height="100">
     <![CDATA[picture100x100.jpg]]>
</im:image>
```

And simply use this delegate method:

`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock`

**if it is the only element enclosed within CDATA block**.

Hope you understood ;)